# Python Kivy: AntiAliasing for Canvas

Tags: python, canvas, kivy, fxaa

When I'm creating a Widget, and draw a circle on its canvas, the circle hasn't got a smooth outline. To fix that, I thought an EffectWidget would help me, as it once did with an ImageWidget on it. But enabling FXAAEffect on it after drawing a circle on its canvas didn't change anything. Is there a way, to directly enable AntiAliasing for Python Kivy's Canvas? (Even only for images)

Comment: Have you found a solution for this yet? If you have then please write and answer and accept it.

Comment: This question is over 4 years old. I haven't dealt with Kivy since then, and thus I could never try out the given answer from 2016. I don't remember how I dealt with the issue back then, but the answers to this question didn't help me, as you can read in my comments below them.

Answer (score 0):

The EffectWidget effects only work on child widgets, not its own canvas (due to technical limitations with how it works that are difficult to resolve).

Add a single child Widget and try drawing the circle on that instaed.

With kivy itself you can also enable in-hardware multisampling anti-aliasing, but I don't remember how, and I think it's probably already enabled (at least at a low level) if possible.

Edit: Like the following:

```
<YourEffectWidget>:
    Widget:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 1, 0, 1
            Ellipse:
                pos: 100, 100
                size: 50, 50
```

Comment: "Add a single child Widget and try drawing the circle on that instaed" - I don't exactly understand your meaning. Like Every circle's got his own widget instead of one big canvas? That would work way too slow, as I'm coding for an AndroidGame

Comment: No, just add a Widget to the EffectWidget and use its canvas. I added an example.

Comment: Then post a working example demonstrating the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am using

```
effects: ew.HorizontalBlurEffect(size=0.1), ew.VerticalBlurEffect(size=0.1), ew.FXAAEffect()
```

Comment: Ok, thank you... But my question was posted over a year ago, and I don't even use Kivy anymore :D